# Error log not showing up in my WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, debugging, configuration

I get this error message when I try to put a comment on my site: The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

The error message shows up when a user tries to add a comment at my site www.ibdpage or when they try to register.

To track this down I have tried to look at the log file, but I can't get the log file to get written.

I put the lines in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/public_html/ibdpage/wp-content/debug.log' );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Also, the ibdpage.com site is a subdomain of my site napervillegi.com.  It is one level deep in the file hierarchy.  I have tried both using true or the path to the debug.log file as the argument to define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',...) and it failed both ways.

Meantime, what do I need to do to find out why the error log is not being generated?

Answer (score 1):

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Its already in wp.config.php file

You just need to change it like

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

If still you are not able to see the error while adding comments

then add this below line in theme at the top of functions.php file at

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Hope it will work
Thanks

Comment: Did that already.  The 'WP_DEBUG' was mentioned above.  Other tries included @ini_set.  Still no success.  Any idea where a failed file write would get logged?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simpler:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

If that is still giving you the "site is experiencing technical difficulties" error, temporarily rename your `.htaccess` file to ensure there are no strange rewrites causing an issue. This should at least get the logs being written to `/wp-content/debug.log` inside of this WordPress install.

Regarding the full path however:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/public_html/ibdpage/wp-content/debug.log' );
```

When accessing the filesystem, even though /public_html/ might be the highest you can go in the file structure of your cPanel account, often you need the full path, which would be something like this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/home/accountname/public_html/ibdpage/wp-content/debug.log' );
```

Look for **Home Directory** in your cPanel or File Manager to discover the correct path.

Comment: I originally had define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); without success, but I'll try the HomeDirectory advice.   Any idea where I can look to see a logged failed file write?